# pull data from json file into an angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
angular.module('testJsonLoadApp')
  .factory('LoadJsonFactory', function($http) {
    var jsonLoad = {
      fetch: function() {
        return $http.get('../../test.json').then(function(data) {
          return data;
        });
      },

    };

    return jsonLoad;
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, LoadJsonFactory) {
    var a = [];
    LoadJsonFactory.fetch().then(function(items) {
        a = items;
    });
    $scope.data = a;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="datum in data">{{datum.id}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the Json file content

```
[{"id": "0","Name": "Items 0", "Description": "Description 0"},
{"id": "1","Name": "Items 1", "Description": "Description 1"},
{"id": "2","Name": "Items 2", "Description": "Description 2"}]
```

The variable 'a' in the controller is not getting updated with the array generated from the json file. However if I use the $scope variable to bind the array directly, then it works.

```
LoadJsonFactory.fetch().then(function(items) {
            $scope.data = items;
        });
```

The above code works.

Is there a way I can assign it to a controller variable and then bind it to the scope variable?

Comment: Any help much appreciated!!!

Comment: try this `a = items.data`

Comment: Tried items.data too, but still unable to get the array there.

Answer (score 0):

This call is Async

```
LoadJsonFactory.fetch().then(function(items) {
    a = items;
});
```

This executes before the call has finished

```
$scope.data = a;
```

So No you cannot do it this way. `a` will always be empty upon assigning to `$scope.data`

You can do this however if it suits you, which the same with what you have working, just a little clearer.

```
LoadJsonFactory.fetch().then(onFetch);


function onFetch(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
}
```

Comment: Actually by binding $scope.data within the fetch() method of factory, I'll be able to obtain and display the array from json file. But the problem for me is: In my application, I have a directive which has its own controller. I need to read the json file through a factory and assign it to an array variable which is to be used in the main controller and the directive controller as well (same instance). If there are 2 different instances of the array, then the values won't match for me. :(

Comment: make a different question and ask exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your service response `LoadJsonFactory` to a variable within your service, instead of in your controller, and then just call it from any controller.

For example:

```
.factory('LoadJsonFactory', function($http) {

var jsonResponse = [];

return {
    fetch: function() {
       return $http.get('../../test.json').then(function(data) {
       jsonResponse = data;
     });
    },
    getResponseResult: function() {
      return jsonResponse;
    }
   }
 })
```

Comment: Even if I'm using just `var a;` without declaring it as an array, it doesn't work. Also if I'm directly binding the scope variable `data` inside the function it works.

Comment: Did the update work for you by defining a new function in the factory? I'm afraid it didn't work for me..

Comment: It does work for me. You would need to post your code, including where you call it in your controller, for me to see if there's a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that LoadJsonFactory's $http call is asynchronous. Your `$scope.data = a` is run *immediately* after LoadJsonFactory is called.

I've made a quick plunkr that illustrates this—open console to see what I mean. (I've also cleaned up the LoadJsonFactory a bit so it more clearly returns a promise.)

https://plnkr.co/edit/Ns1iQdvhKT6DXrfjrOjm

Assigning to $scope.data within success function of the promise works because at that point the promise is resolved and the assignment triggers a digest that updates the two-way binding.